# How to checking if a point lies in a polygon in the data stored in the redshift table?

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, amazon-redshift, shapes

I am trying to check if a point i.e.  combination lies in a polygon which is coming from a shape file(.shp). 
The points that I am trying to check are part of a redshift table which has 3 columns in it,the longitude and latitudes along with an ID.

```
Redshift Table 
**ID | LON    | LAT   | Flag**
1    | 108.21 | 21. 6 | 
2    | 116.1  | 80.2  |
```

For a small dataset I have been able to do the check and create a flag which tells if a point lies in the polygon by importing the data and the shape file into R and then by doing the check.

But the dataset that I need to create a flag on has around 100M records and I am not sure if R will be able to handle so many records.

Can someone help me with this as in what is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: what is the formula that you want to implement? perhaps it can be done in python within redshift

Comment: Currently I am using a function in R called `over` which is from the **rgeos** package. It takes 2 dataframes as input, one is the shape file and the other is the dataframe containing the test coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can break you polygon dataset into chunks, run the "within" logic against every chunk and full point dataset in R and append the result to the final output dataset (similar to parallelization but on a single node)

2) you can import your polygon data into Redshift as WKT, install some geographic Python library in Redshift and call its functions in a join condition (which will cause nested loop join that is quite slow, and spatial indexes are not supported)

3) another more exotic approach of replicating the spatial index functionality (what I would do):

- calculate bounding boxes for polygons in Redshift (the square that frames the polygon), which can be expressed merely as min and max lat and long (you can write the Python UDF for that, it's just min and max of the lat and long arrays derived from WKT representation)
- define prospective pairs by running the join of point table to polygon table where the condition is point lat between min lat and max lat of the polygon table, same with long (i.e. point is inside the box), it's going to run quite fast on the dataset of any size, esp. if you have min lat and min long as the sort key of the polygon table
- use the pair dataset with polygon shapes and point coordinates to define true intersections using any tool outside Redshift (dataset is going to be much smaller)

Comment: nice answer as usual @alexyes